# Format output as JSON object instead of array

Tags: json, sqlite, aggregate, aggregate-functions

Table:

```
sqlite> select * from t;
id  name  date
--  ----  ----
1   ...   ...
2   ...   ...
3   ...   ...
```

Schema:

```
sqlite> .schema t
CREATE TABLE t (id integer primary key, name text, date text);
```

The output can be formatted in JSON as an array of objects:

```
sqlite> .mode json
sqlite> select * from t;
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "...", "date": "..."},
    {"id": 2, "name": "...", "date": "..."},
    {"id": 3, "name": "...", "date": "..."}
]
```

However, I would like an object where the keys are integers and the values are objects:

```
{
    1: {"name": "...", "date": "..."},
    2: {"name": "...", "date": "..."},
    3: {"name": "...", "date": "..."}
}
```

Is this possible with SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function [`json_object()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jobj) to get a json object for the `name` and `date` of each row and [`json_group_object()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jgroupobject) to aggregate all rows:

```
SELECT json_group_object(
         id, 
         json_object('name', name, 'date', date)
       ) AS result
FROM t;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cPai71ib).